# Get Visibility of product Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, visibility

I want to know how to get visibility of product using Magento 2. I have a product that is set to "not visible individually" and want to remove it from a collection.

I have tried below methods:

```
$product->getVisiblility();
$product->getVisibleInCatalogStatuses();
$product->getVisibleStatuses();
$product->isVisibleInCatalog();
$product->getVisibleInSiteVisibilities();
$product->isVisibleInSiteVisibility();
```

But all products return the same value "1" for `$product->isVisibleInCatalog` visible or not.

I have reindexed via command line also and set the visibility for all stores to be not visible however still the issue persists.

Comment: and what's wrong with all the methods returning the same?

Comment: Well i would hope the values would change depending on visibility...

Comment: aaah ok. Try reloading the product over the repository and check if the methods return correct value.

Comment: Sorry yeah bit confusing the wording after all the methods that i tried. Im not sure what you mean by reloading product over the repository however.

Comment: Inject `\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface` in your controller/block/service/whatever and then reload the product with `$productReloaded = $this->productRepository->get($product->getSku());`

Comment: Thanks for your help but think i was just being complete idiot looking back at code ha

Comment: Ah no still not working thought i noticed something but no. Ive also tried reloading the products using your method but all products show as a 1

Comment: is there any solution to this?

Comment: I think that it should work not sure if i made a mistake somewhere in my code at the time did you try any of the above?

Answer (score 7):

You can get it via this :

```
$_product->getAttributeText('visibility');
```

Get visiblity text:

```
$_product->getAttributeText('visibility')->getText();
```